# understanding why a function is analytic at a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sinh x }$. We know $f(x) $ is $\mathbf{not}$ analytic at $x=0$. Prof claims that

$$ xf(x) = \frac{x}{\sinh x} $$

is analytic at $x=0$. But, how come? I dont think it is true. Maybe it has to do that we can find a power series expansion around $x=0$ of the function $xf(x)$?

Comment: Well, the extra $x$ factor is added to make something go to zero, that previously was not going to zero in $f(x)$. Find out what that thing is. Further, see that $x^2f(x)$ etc. are all analytic now.

Comment: $x=0$ is a removable singularity for $\dfrac{x}{\sinh x}$

Comment: $\frac{x}{x}$ **is analytic** at $x=0$. Here it is the same with $\sinh x= x \, h(x)$ for some function $h(x)$ analytic at $x=0$ and $h(0) \ne 0$, so that $\frac{x}{\sinh x} =\frac{x}{x \, h(x)} =  \frac{1}{h(x)}$ **is analytic** at $x=0$